# How would I retrieve a CSV file that I stored in MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am able to upload a CSV document to my MongoDB server using GridFS. However, I seem to be having issues retrieving the CSV data from the database to parse. It might be something simple I am overlooking, but I am not sure. My code is below.

Back end snippet for uploading

```
var storage = new GridFsStorage({ 
    url: mongoURI,
    file: (req, file) => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const filename = file.originalname + Date.now()
        const fileInfo = {
            filename: filename,
            bucketName: 'Uploads',
        }
        resolve(fileInfo)
      });
    }
  });
  const upload = multer({ storage });

routerUpload.post('/upload', upload.single('files'), (req, res) => {
    //res.json({file: req.file})
    res.redirect('/')
})
```

Front end snippet for retrieving via Axios

```
axios
.get(`http://localhost:5000/api/files/${fileName}`)
.then(res => {
  console.log(res.data)
})
.catch(err => 
{
  console.log(err)
})
```

`res.data` returns this in the console

```
{_id: "5d9df2605cbe7e430047616f", length: 59, chunkSize: 261120, uploadDate: "2019-10-09T14:44:48.526Z", filename: "TestDocument.csv", …}
chunkSize: 261120
contentType: "application/vnd.ms-excel"
filename: "TestDocument.csv"
length: 59
md5: "3d203d830d4c39ea7dabfb4562aa5032"
uploadDate: "2019-10-09T14:44:48.526Z"
_id: "5d9df2605cbe7e430047616f"
__proto__: Object
```

It looks like I am able to get the fs.files portion of the CSV, but I need the chunk portion containing the data. Any ideas would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to figure it out from the code below, hope this helps others. I just used `gfs.createReadStream` to pipe the output.

```
routerUpload.get("/files/:filename", (req, res) => {
  gfs.files.findOne({ filename: req.params.filename }, (err, file) => {
    // Check if files
    if (!file || file.length === 0) {
      return res.status(404).json({
        err: "No file exists"
      });
    }

    // Check if csv
    if (file.contentType === "application/vnd.ms-excel" || file.contentType === "application/vnd.ms-excel") {
      // Read output to browser
      const readstream = gfs.createReadStream(file.filename);
      readstream.pipe(res);
    } else {
      res.status(404).json({
        err: "Not a csv"
      });
    }
  });
});
```